# Awk sum rows in csv file based on value of three columns

Tags: bash, awk

Iam using this awk to process csv files:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"} (NR==1) {$9="TpmC"; print $0} (NR>1 && NF) {a=$2$5; sum6[a]+=$6; sum7[a]+=$7; sum8[a]+=$8; other[a]=$0} END
{for(i in  sum7) {$0=other[i]; $6=sum6[i]; $7=sum7[i]; $8=sum8[i]; 
$9=(sum8[i]?sum8[i]/sum6[i]:"NaN"); print}}' input.csv > output.csv
```

it is doing sum of rows in columns 6,7,8 and then division of sum8/sum6 everything for rows with the same value in column 2 and 5.

I have two questions about it
1) I need the same functionality but all calculations must be done for rows with the same value in columns 2,3 and 5. i have tried to replace

```
a=$2$5;
```

with

```
b=$2$3; a=$b$5;
```

but its giving me wrong numbers.

2) how can i delete all rows with value:

```
Date;DBMS;Mode;Test type;W;time;TotalTPCC;NewOrder Tpm
```

except first row?

here is some example of csv.input:

```
Date;DBMS;Mode;Test type;W;time;TotalTPCC;NewOrder Tpm
Tue Jun 16 21:08:33 CEST 2015;sqlite;in-memory;TPC-C test;1;10;83970;35975
Tue Jun 16 21:18:43 CEST 2015;sqlite;in-memory;TPC-C test;1;10;83470;35790
Date;DBMS;Mode;Test type;W;time;TotalTPCC;NewOrder Tpm
Tue Jun 16 23:35:35 CEST 2015;hsql;in-memory;TPC-C test;1;10;337120;144526
Tue Jun 16 23:45:44 CEST 2015;hsql;in-memory;TPC-C test;1;10;310230;133271
Thu Jun 18 00:10:45 CEST 2015;derby;on-disk;TPC-C test;5;120;64720;27964
Thu Jun 18 02:41:27 CEST 2015;sqlite;on-disk;TPC-C test;1;120;60030;25705
Thu Jun 18 04:42:14 CEST 2015;hsql;on-disk;TPC-C test;1;120;360900;154828
```

output.csv should be

```
Date;DBMS;Mode;Test type;W;time;TotalTPCC;NewOrder Tpm;TpmC
Tue Jun 16 21:08:33 CEST 2015;sqlite;in-memory;TPC-C test;1;20;167440;71765;3588.25
Tue Jun 16 23:35:35 CEST 2015;hsql;in-memory;TPC-C test;1;20;647350;277797;13889.85
Thu Jun 18 00:10:45 CEST 2015;derby;on-disk;TPC-C test;5;120;64720;27964;233.03
Thu Jun 18 02:41:27 CEST 2015;sqlite;on-disk;TPC-C test;1;120;60030;25705;214.20
Thu Jun 18 04:42:14 CEST 2015;hsql;on-disk;TPC-C test;1;120;360900;154828;1290.23
```

Comment: Seeing (some lines of) `input.csv` may help us...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To group by columns 2,3, and 5 use `a=$2$3$5`. To delete the extra header rows, add match statement `($1 !~ /^Date/)`

So the whole awk script becomes:

```
BEGIN {
  FS=OFS=";"
}
(NR==1) {$9="TpmC"; print $0}
(NR>1 && NF && ($1 !~ /^Date/)) {
  a=$2$3$5; sum6[a]+=$6; sum7[a]+=$7; sum8[a]+=$8; other[a]=$0
}
END {
  for(i in sum7) {
    $0=other[i]; $6=sum6[i]; $7=sum7[i]; $8=sum8[i]; $9=(sum8[i]?sum8[i]/sum6[i]:"NaN"); print
  }
}
```